# Very high memory and CPU usage when using Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am creating an app in which I have to show the registered users on the map. I have to display their profile pictures. There can be many of them, may be 1000, 2000, or 3000.

The problem is, by adding every image, its memory usage increases and the app slows down. For example, I am using just this piece of code:

```
UIImageView * imgView = imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like_r.png"]];
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(31.4514885, 74.2642593);
    marker.iconView = imgView;
    marker.map=_mapView;
}
```

Is there a good way to show all users on the map?

Answer (score 25):

Try setting `marker.tracksViewChanges = NO;` to allow the CPU to idle.

Alternatively, set `marker.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like_r.png"];` instead of setting the iconView, which should have a similar effect.

These changes should help with CPU, but may not solve the memory-related issues.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using custom marker and assigning that to `customView` property of marker, first you should set `marker.tracksViewChanges = false`

then if you want to animate your custom marker on selection:

you should enable `marker.tracksViewChanges = true` then after animation finished, set `marker.tracksViewChanges = false`

this trick lets you overcome the high cpu usage of google maps

Comment: You saved my day! I was trying to display about 50 markers with a simple custom iconView and CPU goes up to 100%. With that fix, it stays about 40%

Comment: I am getting 18% usage for 3 markers moving all the time. Kinda high. I tried Apple Maps and it stays below 3%. Switched to mapKit.....

Answer (score 1):

There's no way a user can see all 1000 pins at the same time. You should probably reduce the number of pins displayed by grouping close users together. And when zoomed in you can seperate those pins by increasing grouping factor.

Comment: I am unable to zoom in my map as i displayed 1000 marker, i am worried when user get to 10000 then ? what happen?

Comment: are u suggesting me to do clustering?

Comment: What i'm saying is you should only display maximum of 50-100 pins at a time. If you need to display 10000 pins, most of those pins will be on top of one another. If they are located really close you should display them as one pin. Maybe you can use a custom pin with a counter on it. (displaying user amount near that pin) Take a look at this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/images/utility-markercluster.png