# Adding Custom Images to marker of Google Maps IOS SDK increases lot of memory

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview

I am working on a application that demands users to show on the map like, when user register in to the application he/she upload its picture, when sending picture to server along with picture I scale the image to 0.1 so that its size could be reduced.
The thing is I have to show the user image like 
[image: this is the base image on which user picture will be pasted]

The code to paste user image to this marker I used the code`

```
-(UIImage*) drawImage: (UIImage*) fgImage
          inImage:(UIImage*) bgImage
          atPoint:(CGPoint)  point
{  
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bgImage.size, FALSE, 0.0);
        [bgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, bgImage.size.width, bgImage.size.height)];
        [fgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( point.x, point.y, fgImage.size.width, fgImage.size.height)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   
        return newImage;
}
```

fgImage is user pic image and bgImage is base image. 
this fuction returns me the complete image with green marker and rounded user image pasted on it. After that  I pass this image to Map Marker

```
 marker.icon =  [self drawImage:[self makeRoundedImage:img radius:25] inImage:markerImage atPoint:CGPointMake((markerImage.size.width/2)-25, (markerImage.size.width/2)-25)];
```

The problem I am facing is I have created 70 testing users and App memory grows to 100 MB with so many custom markers on it.
Please suggest me the best solution to handle this situation .
Thanks.

Comment: hey hassan, can you explain me how did you get that marker with rounded image?

Answer (score 0):

If multiple markers use the same image, make sure that they are reference the same object not multiple instances of the same content. You can also check the solution for this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5756).

Also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116644/memory-and-cpu-go-very-high-when-using-google-map-sdk-to-ios) for more information.