# GMSMarker rendering and lag issues

Tags: swift, gmsmapview

I added 8 markers to GMSMapView

The markers has simple custom view that is build from UIImage and UILabel

The Label should change text every 10 seconds

The problem is that every time when the text needs to be changed, there is a little lag in the UI (Which mostly noticeable when scrolling a table view)

The way I'm doing it is within a loop:

**In order to stop the rendering and let the cpu rest:**
marker.tracksViewChanges = false

Wait 10 seconds...

**In order for the text change to take effect:**
marker.tracksViewChanges = true

marker.custoView.label.text = "some new text"

**Continue loop**

Is there a way to do it without the lag issue in the UI?

Comment: I guess setting the label is not a problem. But UIImage might be. Did you try to run it within `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` ?

Comment: It also happens if I remove the image. It guess that the problem is because the whole view gets redrawn again on the map. The thing is that it is just 8 markers... so it is weird

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2082 - it is for react native, but it seems, that trackViewChanges is the culprit. Lookup the issues, i found a couple threads with the problem. This one seems solid https://stackoverflow.com/a/49922839/4284508.

Comment: It is exactly what I'm doing. When the text needs to be changed I set this property to true, change the text, and immediately set this property to false. I don't have the cpu issues they talk about since most of the time the property is set to false, excepts for the moment where the text needs to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found some kind of a workaround for this if anyone is interested:

I added a gesture recognizer for the app delegate's window.

Now, each time the user touch the screen I cancel the animation process (marker.tracksViewChanges = false), and reschedule it again.

In this way the lag only happens when the app is static and the user doesn't notice it.